# Sometimes, session is lost when Default.aspx loads in my web application

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I am working on an ASP.net web application that was authored by someone who no longer works for my organization.

I've discovered an odd bug.  It is intermittent issue.

I have a page in the application called default.aspx.  Sometimes, when this page is loaded, the entire session is lost.  I see in the debugger that the Session_Start event fires when this happens.  Sometimes, the Session_End event fires too, but this doesn't seem to happen every time.

I found a custom `sessionState` configuration in the web.config, but removing it does not fix the problem.

Default.aspx directly inherits System.Web.UI.Page and defines no events other than Page_Load.

There is no global.asax in the project.

What could be causing this frustrating issue?

**Update:** I experience this problem when running the application in the built-in server in Visual Studio 2010.  I do not have IIS installed on my workstation.

Comment: Do you know if it's running under it's own app pool in IIS, or if it's under the default one?  Whenever the app pool cycles, you will lose all your session info (if you're using "in process" - default - session setup).  Also, could you tell us the "mode" property of that custom sessionState section?

Comment: Can you check the value of the cookie ASP.NET_SessionId in your browser? Does it keep its value?

Comment: @Malcolm, I tried checking my cookies in MSIE by pressing F12 for the debugger, and then selecting Cache -> View Cookie Information.  I see a number of cookies created as expected, but I don't see on called ASP.NET_SessionId.

Answer (score 1):

A potential problem that could cause session issue (might not be applicable in your case), is that sometimes, some IIS admin set the Application Pool as a WebGarden (ie, Maximum Worker Processes > 1). This is a common hair-pulling scenario.

If you are on VS 2010, VS 2010 kick-start a "mini IIS" each time you start an application. You can see it in the system-tray section. And everytime it launches a new "ASP.Net Development Server", it is a new session.

Just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a scenario where session is lost - In a asp.net page, for a amount text box field has invalid characters, and followed by a session variable retrieval for other purpose.After posting the invalid number parsing through Convert.ToInt32 or double raises a first chance exception, but error does not show at that line, Instead of that, Session being null because of unhandled exception, shows error at session retrieval, thus deceiving the debugging...

Hope it helps, 
HydTechie